# Can I have two classes implement the same interface in COM?

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

My classes are as follows

```
[ComVisible(True)][GUID(...)]
public interface IMyComInterface
{
   void DoThis(string[] params);
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[GUID(...)]
public class MyComImplementation: MyNetClass,IMyComInterface
{
   public void DoThis(string[] params)
   {
      var netParams=params.ToList();
      base.DoThis(netParams);
   }
}
```

This works.

Now I want to add a second ComClass that inherits MyNetBaseClass but uses a filter:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterface.Type.None)
[GUID(...)]
public class MySecondComImplementation:MyNetClass,IMyComInterface
{
   public void DoThis(string[] params)
   {
      var netParams=params.Where(param=>param.Contains("x"));
      base.DoThis(netParams.ToList());
   }
}
```

Does this work, or do I have to define a second MyComInterface with an identical `DoThis` method? Or in other words: must every class that implements a COM-Visible interface have its own, unique COM-visible interface?

Comment: This is *very* common, any COM coclass implements IUnknown :)

Comment: @ Hans Passant: thanks, but I have hardly scratched the surface of this and I have found out that unlimitedly registering and unregistering Com-visible Net .dll's can mess up your development environment pretty bad...

Comment: Not sure what that might mean.  Regasm doesn't register any interfaces guids, only progids and class guids.  Don't use [Guid] unless you are religious about changing them for every project.  Taking a shortcut and skipping that gets you in deep DLL Hell.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: Do you mean that I can omit the [GUID] attributes? Which ones? Now thát would make life a lot easier ;-)

Comment: Yes, the CLR auto-generates them.  All of them.  It does a good job changing the guid when the type declaration has changed.  Very important in COM.  Rebuilding the client project when that happens is still something you have to do yourself.

Comment: @ Hans Passant: Thanks! I removed the GUID attributes and it indeed works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show, is perfectly legal.
The 2 classes will each have their own GUID.  By registering the assembly, the necessary entries will be written in the registry.

In your VB application, you'll be able to do this.  (Sorry, there can be syntax errors in the code below, I don't have enough VB6 knowledge:) ).

```
Dim a As IMyComInterface
Dim b As IMyComInterface

Set a = New MyComImplementation()
Set b = New MySecondComImplementation()
```

Comment: This is exactly how I would like to use the Net Dll, but I only see MyComImplementation and MySecondComImplementation. The IMyComInterface does not show up in intellisense in VB6. I can use the assignment though.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly legal to have multiple objects implementing the same interface. But you register the COM dll by its GUID. When you want to instantiate a COM object, Windows calls the `DllGetClassObject` entry point function, passing it the desired class id.

So this function acts like a factory for the COM object. If you write your own version of this function, you can choose which object to create and return.

I must admit I don't know enough about VB6 to know if it is possible to export your own version of `DllGetClassObject` to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow you. I do not register the class, do I? I register the dll that happens to have two classes implementing the same interface.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. With enough hacking it should be possible to return different COM objects implementing the same interfaces, as long as you can control the `DllGetClassObject` which is calles to instantiate a COM object. I modified my answer accordingly.